# SWAP size made before and after is different

Tags: swap

Actually, I made `/`, `swap` and `/home`. Using a calculator, I made a swap partition of 2.5 x the size of my RAM, i.e. `2.5*4=10 GB` but in Ubuntu it is showing memory of 3.x GB ?

I am going to reinstall it but don't want this to happen again 
And my home is just showing bigger size, I chose something else while installing it.

Comment: Ever heard of false advertising? Example manufacteres not clarifying or refering to the decimal definition of GB (1,000,000,000 bytes) instead of the binary GB (1,073,741,824 bytes ).

Comment: YES , so what should be exact space of 10 gb swap , is 10 gb really needed. or should i go for 8/4 gb ?

Comment: @GokulK please don't add random **bold** and `code` formatting like that.

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is please? [Edit] your post and ask an actual question.